# Double login required, but second entry of username and password not accepted

Tags: macos, user-account, login

When loading my MacBook Pro mid-2012, it prompts me with the usual login screen with my account picture and name such that I just have to enter a password. I enter my password and all is well.

After loading, it then prompts me with the more general login screen, where there are no users available, so you have to click other and enter the credentials. This login screen does not accept the username and password from before.

I have no other accounts on the system so I cannot login through them either. I tried the whole terminal reset password thing, but it said no users were available on the drive. I also tried the safe mode which had the exact same issues.

Comment: sounds really strange a 2nd Login. The only things i can think of are EITHER you have a trojan which uses the 2nd login to trick you into entering your Username and Password OR your Account it selfs may be corrupt so it may work for Login but then some Initialisation fails and as a Result of this you get logged off. Can you remember what was the Last you did before these Problem occured?

Comment: I erased my windows partition

Comment: Also a weird crackling sound which I believe is the CPU fan started.

Comment: When I terminal resetpassword, it says 'there are no users to reset the password for'

Comment: Apparently my hardrive was shot, thanks though